# How is that margin:10+50 works and is valid?

Tags: css, minify

I registered in CSSBattle and found out that the most compact answers used values like `margin:0+50` or `box-shadow:0+0+0+2in#cccccc` and I was wonder how are those values valid if I couldn't find documentation about it.

Comment: Check tips on this page -> https://cssbattle.dev/tips/. It seems like your question is coming from inline style attribute when there are no double quotes used for adding a value. For example `<div style=margin:0+50>`